# How to get id of nested element of div in jQuery/ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

**Scenerio:** I have some divs populated through `foreach loop` like below

```
<div id="div1"><input type="hidden" value="1"></div>
```

and I am populating couple of divs with `div(1,2,3) as id` and `hidden input field with same ids`

In my jQuery/Ajax call I am doing like below

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'URL to Server',
                data: 'id=' + $("#div"+ here I want to get the id of input tag);
```

For example if I want to get the id of `input filed with id="2"` how can I get it ?

Comment: What `foreach` loop? Looks like your code is malformed/missing...

Comment: forget about `foreach loop` its just creating divs. `concentrate` on **AJAX CALL** and try to suggest solution, please read carefully

Comment: Your Ajax code is also malformed and incomplete.

Comment: i got waht i wanted, thx for taking interest anyway,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i am getting you right then you should do like this

`data: 'id=' + $("#div2 input").attr('id')`

`$("#div2 input")` will give you nested input field